# How do I modify Woocommerce shipping price with radio buttons and AJAX update?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I have set a fixed shipping price in Woocommerce.
I need that fixed price to be dynamically changed depending on the selection of the radio button that I created.
For example, if the selected option is `option_1`, the shipping cost should be 10. If the selected option is `option_2`, the shipping cost should be 20.

Also, I need the total cost of `order_review` to be updated in real-time on the front end. I suppose I should do it with AJAX, but I don't understand how. Here's the code:

```php
/**
 * Añade el campo custom_shipping_cost a la página de checkout de WooCommerce
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'agrega_mi_campo_personalizado' );
 
function agrega_mi_campo_personalizado( $checkout ) {
 
    echo '<div id="additional_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Información adicional') . '</h2>';
 
    woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_shipping_cost', array(
        'type'          => 'radio',
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide', 'update_totals_on_change'),
        'options'         => array(
        'option_1'         => 'option_1',
        'option_2'    => 'option_2',
      )
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'custom_shipping_cost' ));
 
    echo '</div>';
}

/**
 * Actualiza la información del pedido con el nuevo campo
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'actualizar_info_pedido_con_nuevo_campo' );
 
function actualizar_info_pedido_con_nuevo_campo( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['custom_shipping_cost'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'custom_shipping_cost', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_shipping_cost'] ) );
    }
}


/**
 * Muestra el valor del nuevo campo custom_shipping_cost en la página de edición del pedido
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'mostrar_campo_personalizado_en_admin_pedido', 10, 1 );
 
function mostrar_campo_personalizado_en_admin_pedido($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('custom_shipping_cost').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'custom_shipping_cost', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

I tried to use AJAX to update `order_review` total in real time but was unsuccessful.
I also tried to create a new custom field, but it didn't work out for me either.